# Bypassing user/username/ part of a file path in VBA code on MAC OS so that anyone can run the macro

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm new to writing VBA on a Mac and understand there are nuances to the syntax. In my VBA script I have an open workbook command :

```
Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("/users/annaglover/Library/CloudStorage/Box-Box/document")
```

but this will only run on my machine though as my username is hardcoded.

I tried just using `~/library/etc.`, to get the active user but it's not working. Everyone at my company has the box driver installed and it's in the same location for everyone, so that isn't the issue. Some of the other tricks I've seen on here are for PC and not for MAC so they aren't working either. I just need help with coding the active user's username in there vs hardcoding.

Comment: ```Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("/users/" & Environ("USER") & "/Library/CloudStorage/Box-Box/document")```